# Import Excel to database in C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, database, excel

I have a huge collection of Excel files.  there are many information privite and my client want to store it in database. And later  they can use the data in the database to rebuild all the Excel report. So do you have  any idea to achieve that? what if I  convert Excel to byte stream to store?

I know that if i put Excel to byte stream, will use more time and space to handle like formats and other thing, and stupid to do that. So  I  would like other way to store the data?

Comment: Do you want to store excel files or data inside them?

Comment: Hi, I wish to store just the data.  and later rebuild the excel based on the datas.  Do you have any good idea?

Comment: Check [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel(v=office.11).aspx) namespace. With it and some googling you should be able to easily make what you need

Comment: try this [http://forums.asp.net/t/1536177.aspx](http://forums.asp.net/t/1536177.aspx)

Comment: That means the client must have the Excel installed,  but I am not sure about his system.

Comment: If he works with excel files I assumed he has excel installed, you can use Spire as Peterman wrote, or OleDB as DevPeter wrote. All thre ways should work work

Comment: Yep, I thought he should have a Excel installed as his report  is just Excel files. Anyway, I am giving a try myself. Thank you, Uriel_SVK.

Answer (score 0):

As Uriel_SVK said,  Interop.Excel should be easy to achieve that.  But if you just wish to store datas, can  also have a try with Oledb.

```
string myConnection ="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\test.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 ;HDR=YES";

    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstr);

    string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet$]"; 
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn);

    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    adapter.Fill(dataset); 

    GridViewXYZ.DataSource = dataset; 
    GridViewXYZ.DataBind();
```

Comment: Yep, I would like to use oledb to achieve that in fear  my client don't  install Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Are you constrained to using C#?  Certain versions of SQL Server offer DTS or SSIS services for moving data in and out of the database from various sources/destinations such as Excel files.  Oracle has something similar in OWB.

Comment: Basiclly, I am handling all his Excel files here.  So I prefer to achieve it in .NET platform.  Or  there might be too much work I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jet OleDB.

The sheet will be the tables and the workbook will be the database. You can use SQl query to produce the data what you want and save it on a datatable/dataset